# Read and write negative numbers with bits

Tags: c#, bit, bit-shift

So with the code below i can save a number (for example 2047) into an using bits and then read it back and it will display 2047. How do i do this if i want to do this for negative numbers (for example -2048)

```
string text = "";
int cnt = 11;
List<int> bits = new List<int>();
for (int i = 11; i >= 0; i--)
{
    int t = (-2048 >> i) & 1;
    bits.Add(t);
}
int value=0;
for(int i=0;i<bits.Count;i++)
{
    text += bits[i];
    value &= ~(1 << cnt);

    if (bits[i] == 1)
    {
        value |= 1 << cnt;
    }
    else
    {
        value |= 0 << cnt;
    }

    cnt--;
}
MessageBox.Show(value+ " " +text);
```

Also the range of numbers i want this to work with is -2048 to 2047

Comment: So you want to convert an int to its binary representation within a string?

Comment: does this answer help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/6790760/697188 Or do you need to write the actual algorithm to do this for homework?

Comment: Please improve the question. As it stands now, you simply seem to misunderstand binary representation of numbers. Your decoding of the list of `int` values fails because you don't take into account the additional set bits that were present in the original value. See duplicate. If you want to encode fewer bits but then store the decoded value back into a conventional integral data type, you need to check your encoded most-significant-bit, and copy it to the remaining higher-power bits in the decoded value.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out after a while of thinking. Just have to add the following piece of code before the output

```
if(value> 2047)
{
    value -= 4096; 
}
```

and then -2048 will actually show -2048 instead of 2048

Comment: This will work in your specific case, but the solution does not generalize well. That said, it certainly is _one_ way to sign-extend the decoded value.